# What to do if Yandex marks the "privacy policy" page as low quality?

Tags: seo, privacy-policy, yandex-webmaster-tools

I setup a website by installing WordPress about two months ago. I did not post anything until yesterday, but prepared the "privacy policy", "terms of service" and "contact us" pages.

Just after my first post, I checked the status on search engines (Google, Bing, Yandex) and realized that Yandex has marked the "privacy policy" page as low quality.

[image: privacy policy]

Actually it is not limited to that page, the "terms of service" page has the same issue from time to time. It seems that Yandex is really confused.

[image: terms of service]

Even if those pages are not indexed, it is not a problem for me, but still I have some worries.

- Since there are just a few pages in total, does Yandex completely blacklist my website due to the low quality pages?
- If this is a problem, how can I fix?

Note: There is a [similar question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51423/do-the-contact-us-and-privacy-policy-pages-affect-seo) on Webmasters SE, but it is for Google.

Comment: What do you think will happen?

Comment: How much traffic dies Yandex send to your site?  It is next to nothing for mine. I don't care what Yandex thinks.

Comment: @SimonHayter I do not know. :)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller At the moment that website has no traffic at all, because I started to post yesterday. I'm planning to add some content about Turkey (however in English), [Yandex's market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/search-engine-market-share/all/turkey) is not bad in Turkey.

Comment: Just keep posting quality content. If Yandex sees your site posting more good content, they may reconsider, or the number of pages they like will outnumber the ones they don't. Hard to say what they'll think a month or two from now. Keep monitoring. It's not like you can take down those pages, they're important to your site. But since there's almost nothing else there yet, Yandex is just judging your site on what's posted right now.

Comment: @ahmedus this is about low quality sites: https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/yandex-indexing/webmaster-advice.html?lang=en